# How to make text scroll through and then display normally

Tags: html, css, css-animations

Trying to make the text in this div scroll all the way through to show the user any overflow.

```
<div class="container">
   <p>Please dont feed the gold fish, they will turn into gremlins</p>
</div>
```

Above is an example of a disclaimer that might overflow the container. The disclaimer can change and it could be longer or even shorter. Is there a way to conditionally animate the p tag to scroll through the content of the tag (if it's too big for the container) and then return to a normal display position after the animation is complete with an ellipses overflow?

Here is a code pen of what I have working so far.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EZEzXr

Comment: I see your example but imo it's already doing what you say you want it to do. Can you explain a little better?

Comment: I updated the pen to illustrate another example that the first iteration doesnt meet. The animation isnt taking into account the length of the text and I was wondering if there's a way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

I have set the animation to move it fully specifying both a transform and a right . I have simplified the vendor-specific styles, they aren't much needed nowadays

Hopefully this is what you want

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.container p {
  position: relative;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  animation: scroll-left 6s linear 1;
}
@keyframes scroll-left {
  0% {
    overflow: visible;
    right: 0px;
    transform: translateX(0%);
  }
  90%,
  100% {
    overflow: visible;
    right: 100%;
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p>Please dont feed the gold fish, they will turn into gremlins and destroy everything they see</p>
</div>
```

Comment: This is awesome, thank you! And thanks for the tip about the vendor specific styles!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that getting the width of the overflow of the p element isn't possible (as far as I know) in CSS. Are you willing to use Javascript?

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .container{
            width:200px;
            white-space:nowrap;
            overflow:hidden;
        }
        .container p{
            left:100%;
            position:relative;
            transition:left 5s; 
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <p id="test">Please dont feed the gold fish, they will turn into gremlins and destroy everything they see</p>
    </div>
    <script>
        var e = document.getElementById("test");
        e.offsetHeight;
        e.style.left = e.parentElement.clientWidth - e.scrollWidth + "px";
        e.addEventListener("transitionend", () => e.style.left = "0px");
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```